# Jquery extract text with regular expression on complete visible text of web page

Tags: jquery, regex, text, extract

I am aware of the jQuery regex plugin of James Padolsey: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

But I need something different:

1. The regular expression should search in the whole visible text of the web page.
2. I want to get the text itself, not the element containing them.

The following will match requirement 1, but not 2:

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    return this.text().match(/\d\d\d/);
});
```

Any idea how i can do this with a good performance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should get you an `Array` of all matches.

```
var text = $('body').text().match(/\d{3}/g);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/WcVDP/).